# Is there a way to redirect HTTP to HTTPS using mod_proxy_ajp or this could be done only at mod_rewrite side?

Tags: centos, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-ajp

What is the easiest way to redirect http to https when mod_proxy_ajp is used?

I have the configuration below for mod_proxy_ajp:

```
ProxyPass /home ajp://localhost:8080/home
ProxyPassReverse /home ajp://localhost:8080/home
```

I was hoping if there is a way to do the redirect here, instead of doing it in the /etc/httpd/conf configs.

Comment: Your ProxyPass is to localhost, setting HTTPS there has no security nor any other benefit. Typically you want HTTPS between the client and your server,  or for securing connections between servers. You'll need some configuration to redirect your clients to https, mod_rewrite is an option or a rewrite directive which is even more efficient: `Redirect permanent /home https://mysite.example.com/home`

Comment: I guess your answer implies, no to my question. Thank you!